# Mongoose array and subarray update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have model:
where stats.d is current date and t and u are some statistics.

```
name: string,
stats: [{
  d: {type: date, default: moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')},
  t: number,
  u: number,
}],
total: number
```

what I am trying to do is to update, check if date is today if today increment t, if today date is not exist, create or add entry to stats array with current date and starting t point. So that I will have stats by date. Here is what I have tried.

```
 model.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params._id}, {$set:{"stats.d": date}, $inc: {total: 1, "stats.t": 1}}, {upsert:true}, function(err, data){

 //success
});
```

But it is not working. I get following error:

```
can't append to array using string field name: t","code":13048,"ok":0
```

Could any point out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in one `update` query.

But you can use `javascript`:

```
model.findOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("req.params._id")
    },
    function(err, data){
        var isDateFound = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.stats.length; i++) {
            if (data.stats[i].d === date) {
                isDateFound = true;
                data.stats[i].t++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isDateFound) {
            data.stats.push({
                d: date,
                t: 1,
                u: 0
            })
        }

        data.total++;

        model.save(data) // or data.save() should work as well
});
```

Without the `upsert` requirement, it's possible to increment the matched array element:

```
db.test.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("req.params._id"),
        'stats.d': date
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            'stats.$.t': 1,
            'total': 1
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Not all, but I need to update stats.t where stats.d is current date as well as total

Comment: @karma so change your question accordingly, it's not understood at all. it looks like you are trying to update all elements.

Comment: Yes you are right, that's what I did, with javascript. Slightly different code, but same concept.